# Empty element causing libxml segfault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, libxml2

I have an xml file that goes roughly like this:

```
<root>
  <children>
    <child />
  </children>
  <otherchildren>
  </otherchildren>
  <morechildren>
    <child />
  </morechildren>
</root>
```

And here's the C that parses it:

```
doc = xmlDocPtr;
doc = xmlParseFile(file);
cur = xmlNodePtr;
cur = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
cur = cur->xmlChildrenNode;

while (cur != NULL){ // Loop through children of root

    // Do my thing

    cur = cur->next;
}
```

When the xmlNodePtr comes to otherchildren, because there are no contents, the next node (the text node) is `NULL`

This gives me a problem, messes with my loop, and causes a segfault somehow.

How do I fix this other than the obvious if statement? There is more xml below `otherchildren` and I can't get it if the loop exits.

Comment: what if you use <otherchildren />? Not sure if this is at all possible in your case.

Comment: No, the whole point is that otherchildren is supposed to hold elements, but sometimes it doesn't and my program needs to handle this.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing and don't think it makes sense. XML is not a list but a tree. You can't walk it by just following a "next" pointer at each step. You need to be able to back up the tree, either using recursion or tracking your location to back up.

Comment: I know it's a tree. I don't need to look at the parents or children, at this point in the program I'm just looping through the children of the root element and when libxml comes across the empty text node of `<otherchildren>` it somehow causes a segfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your .xml, I get:

```
./SOTrials ../Untitled1.xml 
../Untitled1.xml:10: parser error : expected '>'
</root>
^
error: could not parse file ../Untitled1.xml
Speicherzugriffsfehler
```

(Speicherzugriffsfehler = memory fault)

Changing the .xml to

```
...
</morechildren>
...
```

gives:

```
./SOTrials ../Untitled1.xml 
node type: Element, name: text
node type: Element, name: children
node type: Element, name: text
node type: Element, name: otherchildren
node type: Element, name: text
node type: Element, name: morechildren
node type: Element, name: text
```

Looks like your code is better than your xml.

Comment: Hah, nice catch, but that's not the problem here.

Comment: @J V: So what is the problem? (morechildren after otherchildren are picked up after all)

Comment: I don't know, I assumed it was the problem because I didn't see the text element `printf()`d before the segfault. I ran into another problem stopping me from testing more specifically, I'll be back in a few minutes once I clear it up.

Comment: The segfault must have been somewhere else, I can't reproduce any more